# Marking day versus night in DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, style, grid-lines

I would like to mark the periods of day versus night on a `DateListPlot` (and associated plots) by light gray regions for the night.  Here's a minimal example that gives the appearance of what I seek:

```
DateListPlot[
 {{DateObject[{2022, 1, 1}], 80},
  {DateObject[{2022, 1, 5}], 85},
  {DateObject[{2022, 1, 10}], 82}},
 GridLines -> {Automatic, Automatic},
 GridLinesStyle -> {{LightGray, Thickness[0.1]}, Automatic}]
```

[image: DateListPlot with nights marked]

(Note that the nights are not properly marked for *each* day.)

There are three problems with this kludgy approach:

- The `Thickness` in `GridLineStyle` must change as I add more dates to the plot.  I'd rather it be automatic.
- The specification `Automatic` for `GridLines` sometimes puts grid lines every day (as I need), but other times every *other* day, or every *week*.  That of course defeats the approach.
- The harder problem is the following:  The beginning and end of nighttime (and hence the duration of night) changes throughout the year, of course... longer in winter, shorter in summer.  I'd like that subtlety included as well.

This third component problem suggests that basing the shading on GridLines is not the proper approach.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = {{DateObject[{2022, 1, 1}], 80}, {DateObject[{2022, 1, 5}], 85}, 
    {DateObject[{2022, 1, 10}], 82}};

sunrisesandsunsets = Transpose @ Map[Map[AbsoluteTime]@#["Values"] &]@
    Through[{Sunrise, Sunset}[DateRange @@ MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]]];

{min, max} = MinMax@data[[All, 2]];

DateListPlot[data, GridLines -> {Join @@ sunrisesandsunsets, Automatic}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> {{LightGray, Thin}, Automatic}, 
 Epilog -> {Opacity[.3, Gray], 
   Rectangle[Scaled[{0, -1}, {#, min}], Scaled[{0, 1}, {#2, max}]] & @@@ 
    Partition[Prepend[.99 AbsoluteTime @ Min @ data[[All, 1]]] @
      Flatten @ sunrisesandsunsets, 2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Once again, the extraordinary @kglr finds an elegant solution ($+1, \checkmark$).

Answer (score 1):

Here is almost the same approach as @kglr but a little simpler.

```
(*pick a location*)
location = 
  Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}];

(*find maximum value which determine the height of the highlight \
boxes*)
{{startDate, endDate}, {minValue, maxValue}} = 
  MinMax /@ Transpose@data;

(* fix sub-day granularity issue *)
startDate = DayRound[startDate, "Day", "Previous"];
endDate = DayRound[endDate, "Day", "Next"];

(*find sunset for the day before given dates and sunrise for that \
date,also,reap the outputs to use in GridLines*)
{prologValues, borders} = 
  Reap[Rectangle[{Sow@Sunset[DatePlus[#, -1]], 
       minValue*.8}, {Sow@Sunrise[#], maxValue*1.2}] & /@ 
    DateRange[startDate, endDate]];

DateListPlot[data, Prolog -> {LightGray, prologValues}, 
 GridLines -> {First@borders, None}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Dashed]]
```

Output:

[image]

Notes:

- if you remove the location, you'll gain around 2x speedup
- The code assumed the values are positive (.8, 1.2)

Comment: Very nice ($+1$).  Indeed, I had some problems with starting times and time resolution of an hour.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The issue was fixed with `DayRound`.